# ValueError: shapes (3,) and (0,) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 0 (dim 0)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file of (x, y, z). I want to perform the mentioned operation in the code but the shown error of shapes reveals and I don't know where is the problem. Any help!

```
import numpy as np
n = np.array([0.9, 0.43, -0.01])
d = 6.03
with open("D:/Point cloud data/projection_test_data.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        p = np.array([float(number) for number in f.readline().split()])
        v = np.dot(n,p)
        q = np.array(p - ((v + d)*n))
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [79], in <module>
      3 p = np.array([float(number) for number in f.readline().split()])
      4 print(p)
----> 5 v = np.dot(n,p)
      6 q = np.array(p - ((v + d)*n))
      7 lines = str(q)

File <__array_function__ internals>:5, in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (3,) and (0,) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 0 (dim 0)
```

Comment: `p=np.array([float(number) for number in ''.split()])` produces a (0,) shape array.  Do you have an 'empty' line in that file?  What did the `print(p)` show?

Comment: I have checked the file but no empty lines were found

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing np.dot(n,p), these two elements have to be of the same dimention (as explained in the numpy [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)).

p is obtained from:

```
p = np.array([float(number) for number in f.readline().split()])
```

Where you are trying to make an array of floats for each element in the object f.readline().split().
The ValueError says this object is zero dimensional, so there is a problem in f.readline().split().

Edit: You are doing f.readline().split() even if you are in a `for line in f` loop, maybe you want to do `line.split()` instead of `f.readline().split()`.

Comment: But p and n are of the same dimensions, aren't they?!

Comment: I see on row 5 there is a ValueError: shapes (3,) and (0,) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 0 (dim 0)